# Upper limits from Bayesian inference

Tags: particle-physics

While setting an upper exclusion limit for the new physics interaction with Bayesian inference, how do people decide on whether to claim 90% or 95% upper limit from the posterior marginalized pdf?
What are the reasons behind one or another choice?

Comment: It's currently unclear what exactly this question is asking. Please add further information about the context so that potential answerers will know exactly what the issue here is, such as what "new physics interaction" you are talking about or who these people are setting upper limits for it via Bayesian inference.